# How to use Schema.org for the list of my customers?

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I am having trouble using Schema.org and working out which itemtypes to use for the list of my customers.

I have some thing like this:

```html
<div class='famouse-brands'>
<h1> my famous customers </h1>
<div>Company name1 </div>
<div>Company name2 </div>
<div>Company name3 </div>
</div>
```

Not sure if I should use `ItemList` or `customer` and `Invoice`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to display the `Customer` using [schema.org](http://schema.org/)

1. Schema Type [Invoice](http://schema.org/Invoice)

   ```
   <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Invoice">
       <h1 itemprop="description">Invoice 1</h1>
       <div itemprop="customer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
           <b itemprop="name">Jane Doe</b>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```
2. Schema Type [Order](http://schema.org/Order)

   ```
   <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Order">
       <h1 itemprop="description">Order 1</h1>
       <div itemprop="customer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
           <b itemprop="name">Jane Doe</b>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

You can use any of above schema as per your current website structure.

Also, you can refer the detailed schema demos with Microdata, RDFa and JSON-LD on the links given above for **Invoice** and **Order**.